# System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. in Xamarin

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

```
UserAvatar = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.profilePic);  
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)UserAvatar.GetDrawableState();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.Bitmap;
MemoryStream baos = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, baos);
byte[] bb = baos.ToArray();
String image = Base64.Encode(bb, Base64Flags.Default).ToString();
```

I am trying to encode imageview image to base64 string format but i am getting  cast exception in

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)UserAvatar.GetDrawableState();
```

into this aboue line please me.I am implemeting this code in c# Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

This happens because, actually, `GetDrawableState()` returns an `int[]` and represents ID's of states.
To get drawable from ImageView you should use `GetDrawable()` as shown here https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14939/is-there-a-way-to-get-bitmap-from-imageview

Answer (score 0):

As already noted [`GetDrawableState()`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Views.View.GetDrawableState()/) returns a `int32[]` value.

---

Refer the below code in **Image** to **Base64** Conversion.
It will help you sometimes.

**Base64 to Bitmap :**

```
public Bitmap Base64ToBitmap(String base64String)
{
    byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.Decode(base64String, Base64Flags.Default);
    return BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.Length);
}
```

---

**Bitmap to Base64 :**

```
public String BitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.ToByteArray();
    return Base64.EncodeToString(byteArray, Base64Flags.Default);
}
```